# How to extract some specific values from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still trying to create an app where the user could transform his name or a word with chemical elements (like breaking bad logo).

The user will enter a word in a text field and when he'll submit it will return him the word with the corresponding chemical symbols if they match, or it will display the "raw" letters if they don't match.

ex: If no symbol matches I am keepking the initial entry so it could be: hello => **He** ll **O** (bold char represent the existing chemical symbols)

*I know this could be done in js, but the challenge is ROR (btw I don't know any js...)*

In an earlier question I had just a hash like:

```
     symbols =
      {"cr" => "Cr",
      "sb" => "Sb",
      "ag" => "Ag",
      "ar" => "Ar",
      "as" => "As",
      "at" => "At",
      "n"  => "N",
      "ba" => "Ba",
      "bk" => "Bk"}
```

and I was using `name.downcase.gsub!(Regexp.union(symbols.keys), symbols)`to transform the user entry. Actually I need more datas... that's why I chosen the json file.

Like on this picture i will need to use:

- **"number"**
- **"small"**
- **"molar"**

[image]

(and the **"name"** will appear in a caption below)

I have organized a **.json** file with all the symbols I may need in the app and stored it in my `config/periodic_table.json` (pasted just a sample cause it's very long).

#### 1°) If a user enter "hello" how do I loop to search for the "he" hash and print the "name","number", "small" and the "molar"

#### 2°) I will use the json as a database (I will use heroku to deploy) so do I have anything to transform for using json and pg together?

```
[ "symbols"

        {
           "h": {
                "name": "Hydrogen",
                "number": 1,
                "small": "H",
                "molar": 1.00794
            },
            "he": {
                "name": "Helium",
                "number": 2,
                "small": "He",
                "molar": 4.002602
            },
          "b":  {
                "name": "Boron",
                "number": 5,
                "small": "B",
                "molar": 10.811
            },
            "c": {
                "name": "Carbon",
                "number": 6,
                "small": "C",
                "molar": 12.0107
            },
            "n": {
                "name": "Nitrogen",
                "number": 7,
                "small": "N",
                "molar": 14.0067
            }
    }
]
```

#### I will need to loop first with the symbols that contain 3 chars, then 2 then 1... shall i change anythin in the json, like an harray for the hashes that contains 3 chars, another for 2 chars , and for 1char?

Comment: I have a question unrelated - but I've been thinking of this since I read your first post - how do you plan to handle, say, Nancy, will you take the N for nitrogen or the Na for Sodium - that's but one example - but I'm curious how you plan to deal with it - and using your example - how do you choose to use helium for he instead of hydrogen for h?

Comment: I edited my post while you were asking I believe... It will need to loop and search for the symbols with 3 chars, then 2 chars, the 1 char

Comment: Well i'm weird - so i'd convert the input string to an array - i'd reverse the order - then i'd write some sort of recrusive loop (i'm not good at those things) that starts with three, and if it works, pops all three off - (or you can use slice - i'm just bad at slice) and if it doesn't work - check two - check one - and then default - probably run a case statement with complexity?  I can see how to do it in my brain but i can't code it :)

Comment: I have the idea too but I  can't find the code yet

Comment: You won't 'find' the code - you'll have to write it - it's pretty basic ruby stuff once you break it down - just write your pseudo code out

Comment: I meant i can't figure out how to write it... it's blurry in my head...

Comment: @Nelly-Johan I think It's better to have an **Elements** model, This way you could run simple queries like `Element.find_by name: 'hydrogen'`,and also a **Name** model which every name has_many elements :through :elmenents_combination

Comment: okay... sounds intersting, but can i put this json file somewhere in the model? how do I had it to the database?

Comment: @Nelly-Johan No you will simply create a new database table called elements each elements has name and symbol, number, etc... then you use `seed.rb` to seed your table with the periodic table data. you can use `rails generate scaffold Element name:string { other attributes goes here } ` then migrate  using `rake db:migrate` and you can use this railsCast http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data to know more about how to seed data to data base, also using a gem like carrierwave you can attach a photo to every Element to use it later for display

Comment: if I do this (maybe it's wrong)
`rails generate scaffold Element symbol:string { name:string, number:integer, small:string, molar:integer }`

I have this error zsh: parse error near `}'

Comment: I don't need carreirwave as I am not using any image (actually)... the attached picture is a screenshot of what i want (I will create div to display the matching symbols with the different elements_ number/small/molar_)

Comment: @Nelly-Johan dont use the curly bracket {}, I was using them to indicate the part you should write, you should read the section about scaffolding in this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate , Also about the image; Image should be part of the element model

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun thank u , I think there is a misunderstood, I don't want to use images. No images match to any symbol. Everything is text or integer that will come in a div to represent the symbol.
For exemple if my word is "bacon" it  contains **"Ba"** , **"Co"** and **"N"**. So a div with: `number => 56, small=> "Ba", molar: 137.327` , 
`number => 27, small=> Co", molar: 58.933193` ,  `number => 7, small=> "N", molar: 14.0067` will be displayed inline

Answer (score 0):

Correct Json Format

```
[{
"symbols":{
  "h":{
     "name": "Hydrogen",
     "number": 1,
     "small": "H",
     "molar": 1.0079
       },
  "he":{
     "name": "Helium",
     "number": 2,
     "small": "He",
     "molar": 4.002602
        },
  "b": {
     "name": "Boron",
     "number": 5,
     "small": "B",
     "molar": 10.811
       },
  "c": {
    "name": "Carbon",
    "number": 6,
    "small": "C",
    "molar": 12.0107
       },
  "n": {
     "name": "Nitrogen",
     "number": 7,
     "small": "N",
     "molar": 14.0067
       }
  }
}]
```

Comment: @vivek Those are not answers, I know you cannot comment and so you use answers, But please consider delete them. As they cannot be marked as Correct. and to give the question a chance to be answered